# resumeable file download issue -> when file size is more than Int32.MaxValue(2GB) (big files)

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, download, resume

i found the code below in stackoverflow for resumeable file downloads :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Net;

namespace WindowsServer.Classes
{
    public class DownloadFile
    {

        public static bool DownloadFileMethod_2(HttpContext httpContext, string filePath, long speed)
        {
            // Many changes: mostly declare variables near use
            // Extracted duplicate references to HttpContext.Response and .Request
            // also duplicate reference to .HttpMethod

            // Removed try/catch blocks which hid any problems
            var response = httpContext.Response;
            var request = httpContext.Request;
            var method = request.HttpMethod.ToUpper();
            if (method != "GET" &&
                method != "HEAD")
            {
                response.StatusCode = 501;
                return false;
            }

            if (!File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                response.StatusCode = 404;
                return false;
            }

            // Stream implements IDisposable so should be in a using block
            using (var myFile = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            {
                var fileLength = myFile.Length;
                if (fileLength > Int32.MaxValue)
                {
                   response.StatusCode = 413;
                    return false;
                }

                var lastUpdateTiemStr = File.GetLastWriteTimeUtc(filePath).ToString("r");
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
                var fileNameUrlEncoded = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(fileName, Encoding.UTF8);
                var eTag = fileNameUrlEncoded + lastUpdateTiemStr;

                var ifRange = request.Headers["If-Range"];
                if (ifRange != null && ifRange.Replace("\"", "") != eTag)
                {
                    response.StatusCode = 412;
                    return false;
                }

                long startBytes = 0;

                // Just guessing, but I bet you want startBytes calculated before
                // using to calculate content-length
                var rangeHeader = request.Headers["Range"];
                if (rangeHeader != null)
                {
                    response.StatusCode = 206;
                    var range = rangeHeader.Split(new[] { '=', '-' });
                    startBytes = Convert.ToInt64(range[1]);
                    if (startBytes < 0 || startBytes >= fileLength)
                    {
                        // TODO: Find correct status code
                        response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                        response.StatusDescription =
                            string.Format("Invalid start of range: {0}", startBytes);
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                response.Clear();
                response.Buffer = false;
                response.AddHeader("Content-MD5", GetMD5Hash_2(filePath));
                response.AddHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
                response.AppendHeader("ETag", string.Format("\"{0}\"", eTag));
                response.AppendHeader("Last-Modified", lastUpdateTiemStr);
                response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" +
                                                            fileNameUrlEncoded.Replace("+", "%20"));
                var remaining = fileLength - startBytes;
                response.AddHeader("Content-Length", remaining.ToString());
                response.AddHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

                if (startBytes > 0)
                {
                    response.AddHeader("Content-Range",
                                        string.Format(" bytes {0}-{1}/{2}", startBytes, fileLength - 1, fileLength));
                }

                // BinaryReader implements IDisposable so should be in a using block
                using (var br = new BinaryReader(myFile))
                {
                    br.BaseStream.Seek(startBytes, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                    const int packSize = 1024 * 10; //read in block，every block 10K bytes
                    var maxCount = (int)Math.Ceiling((remaining + 0.0) / packSize); //download in block
                    for (var i = 0; i < maxCount && response.IsClientConnected; i++)
                    {
                        response.BinaryWrite(br.ReadBytes(packSize));
                        response.Flush();

                        // HACK: Unexplained sleep
                        var sleep = (int)Math.Ceiling(1000.0 * packSize / speed); //the number of millisecond
                        if (sleep > 1) Thread.Sleep(sleep);
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        static string GetMD5Hash_2(string input)
        {
            // Create a new instance of the MD5CryptoServiceProvider object.
            MD5 md5Hasher = MD5.Create();

            // Convert the input string to a byte array and compute the hash.
            byte[] data = md5Hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(input));

            // Create a new Stringbuilder to collect the bytes
            // and create a string.
            StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            // Loop through each byte of the hashed data 
            // and format each one as a hexadecimal string.
            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
            }

            // Return the hexadecimal string.
            return sBuilder.ToString();
        }

    }
}
```

this method will return false when file size is bigger that Int32.MaxValue!
how can we change this method for large files such as 10GB or More?

Comment: it seems that guy was destroyed because of that question... (poor guy)(so sad for him!) / but dear friends we are here for learn, not downvoting and banning together for just a question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It returns false because the code contains a return false if the file size is bigger than Int32.MaxValue:

```
 var fileLength = myFile.Length;
        if (fileLength > Int32.MaxValue)
        {
           response.StatusCode = 413;
            return false;
        }
```

Does that answer your question, or you want to know *why* the original code added that clause? If you don't understand why, are you sure you want to use this random code found on the intertubez?

Comment: simple debugging would have found this issue too.

Comment: hi, thanks for answer! i understood that code and i know that condition would be never true! but i want to show that method to professional people for getting a best method for download files bigger than 2 GB! (mean editiong and customizing)

Answer (score 1):

```
 var fileLength = myFile.Length;
```

I's a pity that `var` was used here. `fileLength` is a `long` and that will be sufficient.

```
  if (fileLength > Int32.MaxValue)
  {
      response.StatusCode = 413;
      return false;
  }
```

Seems unnecessary.

Comment: What does the `var` aspect have to do with it?

Comment: @gabe Not everybody knows Stream.Length is a long. I would never use `var` here.

Comment: I didn't know it was a `long`, but if it was an `int`, `fileLength > Int32.MaxValue` would never be true.

Comment: thanks guys for help and answer and comments... you are right!it seems it would be never true.but i just want to know why this condition is in there?

Comment: @MoonLight It _will_ be true for files > 2gB. You should remove it and test this method again.

Comment: it works fine after removing! dear Henk Holterman what do think about that code? is it ok for large files or not?

Comment: I think it is OK, I still don't see why that `if(){ }` was in there. Maybe a left-over form even older code.

Comment: @Henk Holterman thanks for attention! did you see my comment after my question?